# Where to find changelog for ESM kernel and packages

Tags: esm

The last kernel for 14.04 LTS is 3.13.0-170, and the latest kernel for 14.04 ESM is 3.13.0-184. Where can I find the changelog for ESM kernels and packages to understand what has been fixed in these newer releases?

Answer (score 2):

### Update 2022-07-14

A more straightforward and structured way to find the outstanding USNs and CVEs applicable to a system is to use the [OVAL](https://oval.mitre.org/) data provided by Ubuntu, combined with the [OpenSCAP](https://www.open-scap.org/) tools:

https://ubuntu.com/security/oval

ESM updates are included (tested on a Xenial system).

Following the instructions on that page will generate an HTML report based on the packages installed on the system. A report in OVAL XML format can also be generated (with the `oscap` `--results` option) for further processing.

The `libopenscap8` package needs to be installed for the `oscap` tool to be available.

### Original answer

The best source of change information that I have found is the [Ubuntu Security Notices](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices) collection.  Publicly-available [changelogs](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/) and [Launchpad access](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/linux-signed) stops at the last public release before ESM.

It is possible to search the USNs based on the Ubuntu release and the USN title. For example:

https://ubuntu.com/security/notices?order=newest&release=trusty&details=linux

To narrow it down to changes for a particular kernel version, the most reliable way I have found is to search through the [ubuntu-security-announce mailing list archives](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/), particularly the [full raw archive](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce.mbox/ubuntu-security-announce.mbox) (in mbox format). The mbox archive can be searched using `mutt`, for example:

1. `wget 'https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce.mbox/ubuntu-security-announce.mbox'`.
2. `mutt -Rf ubuntu-security-announce.mbox`.
3. Press `l` (for limit).
4. Enter the pattern `~s 'usn.*linux' ~b '3\.13\.0'` to list only USN (not LSN) messages mentioning the kernel version of interest.